# JavaScript runtime error: The value of the property 'WebForm_AutoFocus' is null or undefined

Tags: c#, .net

I have been working on a Web Forms Application project.

After the recent Windows 10 update, I'm getting following JavaScript error in IE. It works fine Chrome.

> Unhandled exception at line 545, column 2 in `http://localhost:59508/`
>   0x800a138f - 
>   JavaScript runtime error: The value of the property 'WebForm_AutoFocus' is null or undefined, not a Function object.

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: "Unhandled exception at line 545" – how can anyone tell what's wrong with line 545 without the surrounding code?